# "Too many items" with XPath eq operator for assertion

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xpath-2.0

I am having problem when validating the following XML file against XML schema. The error is "Too many items expected '1', '3' was supplied. In the assert I want to express the following: whenever the OID value equals the BOID value then A_Membership_Degree should be greater or equal to B_Membership_Degree

**Sample XML**

```xml
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="gen.xsd">
<A OID="AA" A_Membership_Degree="0.7" D_Membership_Degree="0.5"  >
  <A1>X1</A1>
  <A2>D1</A2>
 </A>
  <B BOID="AA" B_Membership_Degree="0.2">
  <B1>G1</B1>
  <B2>F1</B2>
 </B>
  <C  COID="AA" C_Membership_Degree="0.3" >
  <C1>G2</C1>
  <C2>F2</C2>
 </C>
<A OID="AAA" A_Membership_Degree="0.8" D_Membership_Degree="0.5"  >
  <A1>X2</A1>
  <A2>D2</A2>
 </A>
  <B BOID="AAA" B_Membership_Degree="0.5"  >
  <B1>G3</B1>
  <B2>F3</B2>
 </B>
 <C  COID="AAA" C_Membership_Degree="0.4" >
  <C1>G4</C1>
  <C2>F4</C2>
 </C>
 <A OID="HHH" A_Membership_Degree="0.8" D_Membership_Degree="0.5"  >
  <A1>X11</A1>
  <A2>D11</A2>
 </A>
 </Document>
```

**Current schema**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert 
        test="if(.//@OID eq  .//@BOID) 
              then ./A/@A_Membership_Degree  
                   ge ./B/@B_Membership_Degree else false()"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="aKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="A"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@OID"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="aKeyRef" refer="aKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="./B"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@BOID"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="aKeyRef1" refer="aKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="./C"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@COID"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="A" type="Atype"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Atype">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="A1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="A2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="OID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="A_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="D_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="B" type="Btype"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Btype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="B1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="B2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="BOID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="B_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="C" type="Ctype"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Ctype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="C1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="COID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="C_Membership_Degree" type="FuzzyValue" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="FuzzyValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message?

Comment: And can you give some examples of XML documents that should be valid and invalid? The schema you've given allows for any number if A and B elements, so _which_ ids do you want to compare? All against all?

Comment: BTW, in the future, try to cut down your questions to the minimum content that reproduces the issue you're asking about (but *do* test that what you're posting can still be run and produces your issue!). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this specific error is that the `eq` and `ge` operators expect their arguments to be single values, but you're providing them with a set of several nodes. Instead of a simple `if` you need an explicit quantified expression like this

```
every $a in A, $b in B[@BOID eq $a/@OID] satisfies
    $a/@A_Membership_Degree ge $b/@B_Membership_Degree
```

The pair of `in` clauses essentially generates a list of all pairs of one A and one B with matching IDs, and the `satisfies` clause checks the membership degree condition for each pair.

Comment: I have another question, what I should write in the assert statement if I want to express the following: in XML file whenever an A node appears, then either a B node or a C node or both should appear such that OID eq BOID and OID eq COID. Basically, regarding the provided XML, the last A node that has OID=HHH should not appear.

Comment: @Reema The way stack overflow works, different questions are best asked as separate SO questions rather than as comments. If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your original question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark to the left, then ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know that. I will add a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath conditional expressions, the `else` clause is not optional.  So adding `else false()` may be the simplest fix.

Some readers (including me) would probably find it clearer to reformulate the assertion as an obviously Boolean value:

```
not(.//@OID eq .//@BOID)
or
(./A/@Membership_Degree ge ./B/@A_Membership_Degree)
```

But clarity is often in the eye of the beholder; you should write in the idiom you and the expected readers of your code find clearest.

Comment: I added the expected XML validated file to the question. In the assert I want to express the following: whenever the OID value equals the BOID value then A_Membership_Degree should be greater or equal to B_Membership_Degree